# Adding new axis to Parallel Coordinates visualization in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, drag-and-drop, drag, interaction, parallel-coordinates

I have hosted my Parallel Coordinates code here:     http://bl.ocks.org/aditeyapandey/d416c90c99e19f7c9209

Upon clicking the paragraph element we can add new axis to the visualization. However, the new axis is not properly interacting with other axes.So if we drag the newly added "Shipping" axis over other axes then it does not throw problem. But, if we drop other axes to "Shipping" the interaction  does not work. Attaching screenshots for reference.

Fig1 Before Adding axis:[image: Before adding axis]

Fig2 With the new axis "Shipping"[image: with new axis]

Fig3 Error when dragging axis over Shipping[image: Shipping interaction error]

PS. I am really sorry for the bad code, it is work in progress and gist has blocked me, as it considers me to be a robot. So, I was not able to modify it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Apparently the drag behaviour was still being called from the earlier code. Therefore we will have to override the previous drag behaviour and then add a new one with all the data fields and axes.

Updated code for reference : http://bl.ocks.org/aditeyapandey/d416c90c99e19f7c9209